# Refund CreditMemo Online

Tags: orders, creditmemo

Currently I am using the code below to refund a full order and create the creditmemo..

```
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100091904');
        $invoices = array();
        foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) {
            if ($invoice->canRefund()) {
                $invoices[] = $invoice;
            }
        }

        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order);
        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            $creditmemo = $service->prepareInvoiceCreditmemo($invoice);
            $creditmemo->refund();
        }
```

But the problem is that the customer paid online with SagePay, this current method ONLY refunds this offline and as you can see this could be a very big problem, anyone got any ways to get around this? Would be much appreciated. Using Magento Enterprise ver. 1.12.0.2

I've not found anything on this before this purely REFUNDING online, not creating the Credit Memo that is the problem it only refunds offline.

Comment: Why is it a problem?  Refunding online means that Magento can talk back to the payment processor and submit a refund.  Refund offline merely makes the record in Magento that it has been refunded (with no update to the payment processor).  Some payment processors don't support this, or require a certain period before it can be done, hence why Refund Offline is available.

Comment: That is a good point but it's a problem because I'd like the refund to be done through the Payment Option, and it works when doing it manually just not through the API or the bespoke code found. Not really got any idea where to go with this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module

Comment: It's not off-topic at all, this was the PHP code in Magento e-Commerce platform. Nothing to do with the SagePay third party module.